# Matrix multiplication error and ggplot output

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

im trying to make matrix multiplication performing a principal component analysis and use ggplot to show the result

```
pca_model <- tbl(sc, "naflights") %>%
select(air_time, distance, dep_time) %>%
ml_pca()
print(pca_model)

# Explained variance:
#
#         PC1          PC2          PC3 
# 0.6975982637 0.3021978609 0.0002038754 
# 
# Rotation:
#                  PC1         PC2           PC3
# air_time -0.12514862 0.001940123 -0.9921361086
# distance -0.99200200 0.016312867  0.1251636066
# dep_time  0.01642742 0.999865054 -0.0001169274

D <- as.matrix(naflights[1:3])
E <- as.matrix(pca_model$components)

# Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
#  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

i have tried:

```
D <- as.matrix(flights[4, 15, 16])
E <- as.matrix(pca_model$components)
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
loadings_pca <- tidy(pca_model)
loadings_pca
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  features     PC1     PC2       PC3
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 air_time -0.125  0.00194 -0.992   
2 distance -0.992  0.0163   0.125   
3 dep_time  0.0164 1.000   -0.000117
E <- as.matrix(loadings_pca[2:4])
P <- D %*% E
Error in D %*% E : non-conformable arguments
mode(D)
[1] "numeric"
 mode(E)
[1] "numeric"
```

I have tried this approach but still getting error : non-conformable arguments.
Anyone can help me with the issue?

Comment: Please limit your example code to the minimum code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. is it possible that what you're looking for is `E <- pca_model$rotation` ? and one more thing `naflights[1:3]` is the first three columns which are: year, month, day, I don't think those are the ones you meant to choose, right?

Comment: @docendodiscimus i have posted only relevant information into first part to show where i take the data and what i want to achieve, below code showing only the trials i have made

Comment: @DS_UNI no, i want exactly pca_model$components, regarding naflights[1:3}, you are probably right! i should been mentioned only columns with air_time, distance, dep_time. thank you for the hint!

Comment: I have tried new way, but still stuck with error, can anyone give me a hint ?